# Redirect output in shell?

Tags: c, shell

I have written a function for the purposes of redirecting output from some command to a file. Something like this

> ls > ls.txt

Here is the function that does output redirection:

```
    int redirect_output(char* cmdline, char **output_filename) {
    int i;
    char* args[MAX_ARGS];

   // int nargs = get_args(cmdline, args);

    for(i = 0; args[i] != NULL; i++) {
        // Look for the >
        if(!strcmp(args[i], ">")) {
              // Get the filename
            if(args[i+1] != NULL) {
                *output_filename = args[i+1];
            } else {
                return -1;  //syntax error
            }
            return 1;       //there is an > 
        }
    }
    return 0;   //no redirect
}
```

The function successfully redirects output from some command to a file, but for some reason it causes other commands to stop working. So for example, my program with `redirect_output` works for something like `ls` but it does not work for something like `cat ls.txt`, if I do not call the function it works for any command. And, by not work it mean it gets stuck. Here are the other important functions.

```
int get_args(char* cmdline, char* args[])
{
    int i = 0;

    /* if no args */
    if((args[0] = strtok(cmdline, "\n\t ")) == NULL)
        return 0;

    while((args[++i] = strtok(NULL, "\n\t ")) != NULL) {
        if(i >= MAX_ARGS) {
            printf("Too many arguments!\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    /* the last one is always NULL */
    return i;
}

void execute(int output, char *outputefile, char* cmdline)
{
    int pid, async;
    char* args[MAX_ARGS];

    int nargs = get_args(cmdline, args);
    if(nargs <= 0) return;

    if(!strcmp(args[0], "quit") || !strcmp(args[0], "exit")) {
        exit(0);
    }

    /* check if async call */
    if(!strcmp(args[nargs-1], "&")) {
        async = 1;
        args[--nargs] = 0;
    }
    else async = 0;

    pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0) { /* child process */
        //if(output)
           // freopen(outputefile, "w+", stdout);
        execvp(args[0], args);
        /* return only when exec fails */
        perror("exec failed");
        exit(-1);
    } else if(pid > 0) { /* parent process */
        if(!async) waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
        else printf("this is an async call\n");
    } else { /* error occurred */
        perror("fork failed");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

And here is my main:

```
int main (int argc, char* argv [])
{
    char cmdline[BUFSIZ];
    char *output_filename;
    char **args;
    int output;

    for(;;) {
        printf("COP4338$ ");
        if(fgets(cmdline, BUFSIZ, stdin) == NULL) {
            perror("fgets failed");
            exit(1);
        }

         output = redirect_output(cmdline, &output_filename);

        switch(0) {
        case -1:
            printf("Syntax error!\n");
            break;
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            printf("Redirecting output to: %s\n", output_filename);
            break;
        }

        execute (output, output_filename, cmdline);
  }
    return 0;
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Use a debugger. It will tell you immediately where the program is "stuck" and allow you to examine the state of the program. That is the right way to debug such issues (and almost all other "not working" issues).

Comment: This has nothing to do with redirection, you program just doesn't pass any arguments to any commands. `ls /tmp` will be executed as if you wrote `ls`, and `cat foo` will "hang" because you just run `cat`, which waits for you to input things. Fix it so that your arguments are passed correctly.

Comment: Make sure that you remove the redirection arguments from the argument list before calling the program.

Comment: @thatotherguy He puts the arguments into the `args` array with `get_args(cmdline, args)` then uses `execvp(args[0], args)`. Shouldn't that pass arguments?

Comment: @Barmar `strace` says this is not happening. I didn't try to debug why.

Comment: @thatotherguy But commands with args do work when I do not call the redirect output function? Calling the redirect output function is what causes them to not work. I'm just not sure why.

Comment: @name I compiled and ran the code you posted, and it does not work with arguments. Maybe you have changed it since you posted it? Something has changed because you call `redirect_output` with 3 arguments but declare it with 2.

Comment: @thatotherguy I'm not sure why. I will update everything with what I have now. Sorry about that.

Comment: @name Your updated version supports arguments but not redirections. The problem is that you're using `strtok`, which destroys the input string. You can't use it twice on the same string data. In your original version, `redirect_output` correctly found the output name, but in the process it truncated "ls /tmp > file" into "ls" (disabling arguments). Your new `redirect_output` doesn't use the input string parameter, so it fails to find an output file. The simplest solution would be to `strdup` the input before calling `strtok` on it, so it has its own copy to destroy.

Comment: @thatotherguy Oh, that makes sense. Thank! Would you happen to know why it is is giving me this `ls: cannot access >: No such file or directory` when I run something like `ls > 4`?

Comment: @name Like Barmar said, you should not be passing the `>` and the `4` as parameters.

Comment: @thatotherguy I'm having some trouble understanding how to "control" that parameters. I'm assuming that I will have to do this in the execute function. Would I just check if the arg is `>` and if so then I will set it to NULL?

Comment: @name That is definitely a pragmatic option. A POSIX shell will accept a redirection anywhere, e.g. `> file ls /tmp` , but there's no reason why your shell should allow it anywhere except the end.

Comment: @thatotherguy I figured out how to do it. I was just misunderstanding the logic of it. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @name Awesome! Consider writing up where you went wrong, how you found the problem, and what you did to fix it as an answer so that future readers can benefit from it (or if you're lazy, delete under the "resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers." clause)